# Uninstall languages

Tags: language

Hosting installed WordPress with like a gazillion languages.

Can I just remove the language .mo and .po's for the languages I don't want or will that break something unintended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can delete the .mo and .po files without any negative effect, but they don't cause any harm by just being there.